# How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string? in c++

Tags: c++, string, strip

How can you strip non-ASCII characters from a string?

I like to know how we can achieve this in c++

Comment: By the way, in a real world application, 'solving' a bug in your code by stripping Unicode characters is a bad idea.

Comment: @Delan Azabani This is happening only at the end of file. I am not able to see that character at the end of file(manually).

Comment: you probably have a bug. Are you sure your string is null terminated ?

Comment: You need to show some code, input and output.

Comment: Your 'string' probably has garbage in it, not unicode

Comment: you can't differentiate between normal ascii chars and unicode chars.. you always have to know the encoding.. so you have to give more information what's going on inside your file.

Comment: If you tell us the exact value of this junk character...

Comment: @crashmstr the value is not constant, every time when I run with same i/p, I am getting different output :(. This is really confusing..

Comment: `char fileData[size_of_file + 1];` Didn't know C++ supported variable length arrays. You should use an `std::vector<char>` instead.

Comment: @Praetorian not formatting the code means?  What you are trying to convey?

Comment: The code you posted had several lines at the beginning and a couple in the middle not indented with 4 spaces. This screws up the formatting and makes it very hard to read the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
struct InvalidChar
{
    bool operator()(char c) const {
        return !isprint(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
    }
};

std::string s;
HypoteticalReadFileToString(&s);
s.erase(std::remove_if(s.begin(),s.end(),InvalidChar()), s.end());
```

Its nicer to define a reusable function for the erase-remove idiom

```
template <typename C, typename P> 
void erase_remove_if(C& c, P predicate) {
    c.erase(std::remove_if(c.begin(), c.end(), predicate), c.end());
}
```

...

```
erase_remove_if(s, InvalidChar());
```

Comment: Is your logic backwards? Should it be `return !isprint((unsigned c))`?

Comment: Strictly speaking, this will remove more than just non-ASCII characters.

Comment: And yes it will remove more than just valid ascii.  You could just use a comparison in the InvalidChar functor.  You could do anything in there you like.

Comment: When debugging, this may trigger an assert failure since `c` will look negative for non-ASCII chars.

Comment: @3noch, where will it assert?  The cast to unsigned prevents negative values being passed to isprint.  Which has prevented asserts for me in the past..  Without the cast, char is promoted to int which is the function signature of isprint.  In fact char is a very unusual type in that it is not the same type as either 'signed char' or 'unsigned char'.  Not sure what the standard specifies - I think the sign of char is probably implementation defined but not totally sure.

Comment: @Pete I'm guessing the cast to `unsigned` is where I saw the assert fail. I'm building with Visual C++ 2013 which might be why I saw it but others don't. (Hence the choice of the word *may* above.)

Comment: @3noch baffling.  But then again, its somewhat baffling that isprint accepts an int and not an unsigned int in the first place.

Comment: @Pete I was wrong. The cast does not assert (which makes more sense). `isprint` asserts `_ASSERTE(c >= -1 && c <= 255);` in the MS version. It must be that the `(unsigned)` cast ends up having no effect.

Comment: maybe try casting to (unsigned char) first.

Answer (score 0):

```
void stringPurifier ( std::string& s )
{
    for ( std::string::iterator it = s.begin(), itEnd = s.end(); it!=itEnd; ++it)
    {
      if ( static_cast<unsigned int>(*it) < 32 || static_cast<unsigned int>(*it) > 127 )
      {
        (*it) = ' ';
      }
    }
}

void stringPurifier ( std::string& dest, const std::string& source )
{
  dest.reserve(source.size());
  for ( std::string::const_iterator it = source.begin(), itEnd = source.end(); it!=itEnd; ++it)
  {
    if ( static_cast<unsigned int>(*it) < 32 || static_cast<unsigned int>(*it) > 127 )
    {
      dest.push_back(' ');
    }
    else
    {
      dest.push_back(*it);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Strip everything that is greater than 127, or see http://www.asciitable.com/ and create a more specific range

```
while (CrtChar)
{
  if (*CrtChar<35 || *CrtChar>127)
   *CrtChar = ' ';
}
```

Comment: this probably won't work: what if the unicode character is two bytes?

Comment: How about [isprint](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isprint/) or something comparable? If you are just checking values, you probably want to strip the lower end too!

Comment: @Thangaraj: What do you mean? If you tried it, it should have worked. You need to show some code now.

Comment: <35? That also replaces exclamation marks and quotation marks with spaces. Also, you're stripping out all newlines, tabs, page breaks and so on. Probably not what you want. +1 on isprint.